# Error: can't rename to "tmp_read_command": command already exists

Tags: tcl

Consider that you rename command and later you again try to rename that, it would show you this error message.

```
Error: can't rename to "tmp_read_command": command already exists
```

What do you do to rename it the first time and not the second time. I mean is there a check condition we can put to find out if a command exists or not.

Details:

Two files:

**include.tcl**

```
proc snps_read_command { args } {
  echo "Hi, I am there"
  eval tmp_read_command
}
proc procedure_a { args } {
  rename -force read_command tmp_read_command
  rename -force snps_read_comamnd read_command
}
```

**test.tcl**

```
source ./include.tcl
procedure_a
source ./include.tcl
procedure_a

read_command
read_command
```

Executing above TCL script gives me this error message:

```
Error: can't rename to "tmp_command": command already exists
```

This comes because I am calling procedure_a twice. First time, it renames and second time when it tries to rename, it cribs. I understand.

Question is:

What should I write to not do this renaming for second time? I tried info commands tmp_read_command and it did not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a check condition we can put to find out if a command exists or not

One of the easiest ways to check is to look at the length of the list returned by `info commands` *with a suitable pattern*. Which sounds more complicated than it is for ordinary commands:

```
if {[llength [info commands tmp_read_command]]} {
    puts "The command tmp_read_command already exists"
}
```

For commands that don't include glob metacharacters in their names (the overwhelming majority of commands!) this becomes a very efficient check at the bytecode level.

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed using llength in my code. Thanks.